# How to reuse this in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

It should look like this:

[image]

- I don't care about reusing it in other applications that need somewhat different looks.
- It's just for display
- Content needs to wrap, maximum 3 lines.

I'm trying to implement it as a derived class of UserControl with XAML defining the visual elements, but I'm not sure if that's the best option.

So how would you implement this type of component?

**Edit**

What I mean by I don't care about reusing is that I want a simple UserControl, where the component is defined in the XAML side of the UserControl. In other words, I don't need a "lookless" component, but one that looks exactly like the one above. Please also note that I'm not asking anybody to create it for me, just give me a few pointers on how you'd implement so I can have something to search.

Comment: I'm confused by this post -- your title asks how to reuse this in WPF, but then your first bullet point says that you don't care about reuse.  So are you starting from scratch with a completely new UserControl?

Comment: maybe I understand -- by "reuse", you're just saying that you want a UserControl that looks like the above, but from your application you just want to specify Icon, TimerInterval, and Content properties, and a Start() method to make the progress circle animate, and have the control render itself differently based on these properties.

Comment: Dave, you got it on your second comment. By "don't care about reuse" I was referring to what I read in some books/articles that if you're designing a new component, then it should be "lookless". In my case, I'm ok if the component looks exactly like the one above, the user can't change the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this:

- create a UserControl with two `DependencyPropertie`s Time and Label
- in XAML bind your Time property with the Arc angle (eventually with a `ValueConverter` to get cartesian coordinates of the end point from the Time value). See [How to create an Arc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745030.aspx) and use the explicit object tags so you can bind the elements you want
- on each Timer timeout increase your Time property value
- bind your Label property with a TextBlock Text for which you allow wrapping and fix a MaxWidth so it wraps when needed